# How to prevent "prod" enviroment to show full symfony4 errors?

Tags: symfony4, environment

Symfony 4.3

After changing  the APP_ENV in .env to "prod", symfony still shows full error pages and not the simplified ones. Is there something i am missing?

What I've done:

- in .env set the APP_ENV=prod
- bin/console cache:clear
- went to localhost:8000/not-existing-rout

.. and seeing the special symfony exception page with lots of debug information. The only difference to "dev" is that the WebProfiler and the "Logs" tab are deactivated.

How to get the simple and generic symfony4 error page?

Comment: Did you set APP_DEBUG=0?

Comment: *"in .env set the APP_ENV=prod"* Do not use .env file in production. See [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#b-configure-your-environment-variables)

Comment: @chinloyal The APP_DEBUG=0 didn't change the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that even though in "prod" environment the extensive error pages where only showed when using the symfony build-in web server (bin/console server:run)

Accessing the app through a regular web server, showing the simplified symfony errors as expected.